# Avoid a modal with inner fixed element to "float" to the left when content gets overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a modal with a content in the center. But at the top I have sort of a fixed header that stays unmoved when scrolling through the content.
The problem is that when the content grows up (height set to 150% on the css), the scroll bars (mac os users please enable scrollbar) breaks the content to the left and the header on the other hand stays in the same position.

How could I make the content to not break up?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Some title</div>
        <div class="text">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: black;
}

.modal{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.content{
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 150%;
    background-color: white;
}

.header{
    width: 60%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
}

.text{
    padding: 80px 30px;
}
```

**Jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ncpds/5/

---

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that if the modal becomes `absolute` instead of `fixed`, the scroll bar doesn't affects the fixed elements. Someone knows why this happens?

**Jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qUXdG/

Why the scrollbar from the modal with `position: fixed` behaves different?

Thanks!

Comment: as a side question, what made you decide to add :before and :after to the wildcard on the box-sizing? I've never needed to do that, but I'd love to know if you find that useful.

Comment: Well, in that case it's not making any diference here. But I find it nice to play with. Seems more natural. But has its disadvantages. Google it to find some articles (=

Comment: I found no articles on it - however I did a test and it is not redundant as I had assumed. Glad I caught that - Good to know!

Comment: Do you have flexibility to change the markup?

Comment: Depends on what change

Answer (score 0):

OK... so - I'm having a really hard time knowing what you want... but I think that your little .click function is to show the change in the width of the page when the scroll bar appears. I *think* that you just need to put an

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

on your html or body... this will ensure that there is always a scrollbar there so that there is not jump.

However... I think the *real* problem is the way you are going about the whole thing. If I knew more of what you were going for, I could help you with that. - but try the overflow idea.

Comment: I thought the same by setting an overflow scroll. But to me it seems lack of a right solution. Maybe? I don't know. In facebook, their "album upload modal" is the same I want to achieve. But they make a "hack" by setting the main content to position fixed and the modal with `position: absolute`...

Comment: Yeah. I was building a website in a website, and I wanted some fixed header in the mini website... but that isn't in the cards. fixed is only to the window and not to any relative container or anything... ended up using an iframe.